# How to clone desktop NVMe into a bigger one?

Tags: windows, windows-11, clone, dd, nvme

I currently have a 2TB Samsung NVMe with several partitions, C being the system partition (Windows 11).

I purchased a 4TB WD NVMe that I'd like to upgrade to.

The Samsung is installed in one of the motherboard's M.2 ports, while the WD is installed via a PCIe card.

Would it suffice to use Kubuntu Live on a USB stick then run the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K status=progress
```

(sda and sdb would be adjusted accordingly)

then turn off the computer, remove the 2TB Samsung, and boot with the 4TB WD?

Would that work without any issue with UFE?

I imagine I can then use the Windows Disk Management utility to resize some of the partitions for the extra 2TB.

Comment: Since one drive is a Samsung, perhaps Samsung Data Migration Software for Consumer SSD, https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/, might help -- I've no experience with it, though.

Comment: I do have it. I am not sure I trust a software running on Windows when I am trying to clone a drive that has the Windows partition. and I only have one desktop PC.

Comment: Windows has Volume Shadow Copy Service, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service, which allows one to take a "snapshot" of a drive to make an image (so far, the sole advantage of Windows over Linux I know). Macrium Reflect (free v. 8 still available, https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html) and similar apps use it to make images and clones *while Windows OS is running and partiton is mounted*. Those images, I find, can be verified and restored without issue.

Comment: ok, interesting, that'd make my life easier if it works. So I do it from within Windows, turn off the PC and remove the 2TB

Comment: Think hard about cloning. Cloning brings OS errors forward. Always best to install the new drive and build the OS new.

Comment: My Windows install is barely 2 or 3 months old, I'd really rather not go through the pain of a new install again.

Comment: thanks for the link to Macrium, @DrMoishePippik 
Do you know how it works in practice? If I am going to clone partition C, D, E and F from within Windows, won't that create duplicate partitions that Windows can't handle?

Comment: So far, I've only used Reflect to clone a *replacement* disk, and to image drives to restore when something goes badly wrong (as has happened on more than one occasion), so I cannot answer what happens on making a second drive a clone. BTW, there's no need to install Reflect or similar tools, if you don't mind booting from the Rescue Environment, which provides both restore and backup capability. The advantage of installing it is in making periodic images without need to reboot.

Comment: I see... thank you :)

Comment: Reflect did not work. I used dd and it worked like a charm, see the solution I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the advice to use a third-party Windows software and clone the system drive directly from within Windows did not work for me and I do not recommend it.

What worked is the following:

- download a Ubuntu distribution ISO (I prefer Kubuntu) and 'burn' it on a USB stick, using software such as BalenaEtcher
- boot from the USB stick and choose to try Kubuntu
- open the terminal
- execute *lsblk* to see the drives you have in the system
- in my case, it was nvme1n1 and nvme2n1 (or something like that)
- be very careful to not get the drives wrong. *if* is the original drive you want to clone, *of* is the drive you want to clone into.
- execute the following command, if you want to clone nvme1n1 into nvme2n1: *dd if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=/dev/nvme2n1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress*
- once this is done, shut down, remove the old drive, and boot with the new drive

this took a little over 30 minutes and worked like a charm

the only drawback is that I have to find a way to resize the partitions if I want them bigger

Comment: I was able to move data back and forth, and resize the partitions as I wanted from within Windows' Disk Management utility

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to invent your own cloning method.

There are multiple free products that can clone your disk *and* even
adjust its size, and they will work from inside your Windows.

See for example
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html),
but there are
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-data-backuper/).

Comment: AOMEI is not free for system disk cloning. 
Can you really clone the entire NVMe from within Windows when one of the partitions is actively used by the system that is constantly writing data into it? That was my thinking behind doing it from a bootable USB stick outside Windows.
I've heard of Clonezilla and Rescuezilla and will give them a closer look.

Comment: Sorry about AOMEI - they apparently changed their plans. Yes, you can use Shadow Copy to copy the entire disk from inside Windows. Other well-known products are Macrium Reflect and GParted (the later requires a boot media).

Comment: @Annathema - You definitely can’t do it with Clonezilla actively, yes, I routinely take live bootable images of Windows using similar programs to AOMEI of course I don’t ever recommend AOMEI or any specific program. However, in my experience, migrating to a larger disk will present partition layouts that will result in the unallocated partition being on the wrong side of your system partition

Comment: just as I expected, this didn't work.
copying from within Windows using Macrium created an exact copy but assigned new drive letters to the new partitions.
Then removing the old drive and trying to boot leads to a EFI error, no doubt because the C partition has been labelled as G now.
I'll try dd from a live Linux.

Comment: The exact error was "Winload.efi is Missing or Contains Errors".

Comment: The disk clone was done incorrectly and did not include the EFI partition. You should be cloning the entire disk, and not the partitions ([link](https://www.macrium.com/blog/cloning-a-disk-with-macrium-reflect-v8)). In addition, the boot partition is always named C, no matter what was its drive-letter when the boot was from another partition. For `dd`, this will work, as long as you copy the entire raw disk, and then you would need to manually resize one or more partitions.

Comment: ... After the cloning, the old disk should be physically disconnected, to ensure that the boot is from the new disk.

Comment: I am pretty sure I selected the whole disk, with forensic copy, so every bit is copied, and not just partitions. I also removed the old disk of course. Still got the EFI error.

Comment: I'll check the software again, in case I forgot a checkbox, but I was careful. I'll go for dd I think. Resizing is very easy after the fact within Windows

Comment: yep, I did it right... clone disk (which automatically selects all partitions), then "forensic sector copy", and it still failed

Comment: the program sees a hidden 16MB partition which I guess is not the EFI partition

Comment: Disk clone should not be concerned with partitions. I hope there's no problem with Macrium on your computer.

Comment: dd worked like a charm, in a fraction of the time it took Macrium to fail. I am not able to resize the partitions in Windows (except the last one) so I'll look for a software to do it, or empty the partitions somewhere, resize and copy back the data